# How to do test in React and Node?

Tags: reactjs, express, testing

I am building a full-stack app with React and Express and I want to ask you something. I decided to improve the app I want to do a test. And what library should I use? I heard about jest or something like that to test React Component but maybe exist a modern solution. To test in express Mocha will be good or again any modern solution exist?

Comment: Also what should i test in React and express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Testing React**

There's a bunch of example [Testing Recipes](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html) for testing rendering, data fetching, events and much more using [Jest](https://jestjs.io).

**Testing Express.js**

I generally recommend [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) for most of JS unit testing, incl. Express' routes and expected results. Have a look at Express' own Mocha [test set](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/test) for examples.

**What to test?**

Well, you should test as many methods as you can. Critical methods first. Test them for returning what they should, and not returning what they shouldn't. Also test how they behave given extreme values, undefined values, etc. Check if they throw the right errors when needed.

When using authentication, ALWAYS test your routes to throw appropriate errors (like 401 or 403) for unauthorised access or insufficient privileges respectively.

If not sure what to test, spend some more time reading about testing strategies :-)